# How to match nginx location with keyWord in the middle of URI

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

Can location directive resolve the incoming requests not at the beginning, but anywhere in the middle of the URI.

for example i have to match location based on environment.

location /uat/ {.....}

location /sit/ {.....}

The request coming in would be /abc/customer/uat/ide

How to make a match when the environment name is not in the beginning of the URI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, use regex case-sensitive `location ~ <regex> { ... }` or case-insensitive `location ~* <regex> { ... }` blocks. [Here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) is `location` directive documentation and [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) is the description of location selection algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. i was trying here https://nginx.viraptor.info/ and it never worked.  However when i tried in actual server config it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this

```
server {
  listen ...;
  server_name _;

  location ~* .*/sit/.*$ {
    ...
  }

  location ~* .*/uat/.* {
    ...
  }
}
```

Breakdown of regex `~* .*/uat/.*`:

1. `~*` -> Makes the matching case insensitive
2. `.*` -> Any character any number of times
3. `/uat/` -> Match /uat/
4. `.*` -> Any character any number of times

Comment: Two `.*` parts of regex isn't needed, just `/sit/` or `/uat/` will be enough. Moreover, I'm not sure, but those `.*` could cause additional computational overhead on regex matching operation.